# Apache runs php files with or without .php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server

My apache runs php files with or without .php extension, How can I disable this and force apache to run php files only with .php extension. I don't want to use .htaccess, this might be an apache config. does anyone know how to disable this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your httpd.conf what extensions are configured, it need need to be following. if there is change in your file you can change it to following and restart the apache

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

more details : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server

please add if anything is missing

Comment: `:-|` I want to disable this not make it more disturbing !

Comment: I need to stop apache to processing php files without `.php` extension

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype clearly says that addtype is for making extensions to have custom mime-types

Comment: check your httpd.conf file , and search for AddType application/x-httpd-php add Replace with AddType application/x-httpd-php .php it should work. check what is configured for you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer but using Addtype as you mentioned did not ever work for me, all by itself, even in PHP 5..

Here's what I've tried that DOESN'T work with this version of PHP:

Options +ExecCGI

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .nusuffix

AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .nusuffix

This worked for PHP 5. Now, does not.

This is for a hosted account, so I must do this via .haccess.